# PySpark UDF for converting UTM error expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a UDF in PySpark for converting UTM to longitude and latitude.

**Error**

```
Caused by: net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)
```

Have tried with different datatype, but without any luck.

**PySpark code**

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import utm

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(531086, 6224626), (531086, 6224626)], ["C1", "C2"])
df2.printSchema()

utm_udf_x = F.udf(lambda x,y: utm.to_latlon(x,y, 32, 'U')[0], ArrayType(FloatType()))
utm_udf_y = F.udf(lambda x,y: utm.to_latlon(x,y, 32, 'U')[1], ArrayType(FloatType()))

df2 = df2.withColumn('lat',utm_udf_x(F.col('C1'), F.col('C2')))
df2 = df2.withColumn('lon',utm_udf_y(F.col('C1'), F.col('C2')))

display(df2)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The main issue was to convert Numpy DType to Float form utm.to_latlon.

This is working

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import utm

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(340000.0, 5710000.0), (573014.00000135, 6221529.99974406)], ["C1", "C2"])
df2.printSchema()

utm_udf_x = F.udf(lambda x,y: float(utm.to_latlon(x,y, 32, 'U')[0]), FloatType())
utm_udf_y = F.udf(lambda x,y: float(utm.to_latlon(x,y, 32, 'U')[1]), FloatType())

df2 = df2.withColumn('lat',utm_udf_x(F.col('C1'), F.col('C2')))
df2 = df2.withColumn('lon',utm_udf_y(F.col('C1'), F.col('C2')))

display(df2)
```

Comment: Conversion of Numpy type to Python type was the missing step in my case. This tip helped a lot. Thanks!